# Flutter Replace Gridview

Tags: gridview, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Use Case: I have a group of articles, when clicking on a group in the gridview, all articles should be displayed in this gridview

My plan would have been to create a second gridview and replace the gridview with the article groups by the gridview with the articles. The gridviews are stored in a variable

> var gridView = new GridView.builder()

When you click on a group, SetState writes the other GridView into the variable, but unfortunately this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on the following way:

First I created a boolean to check the condition, than I safed my Gridviews into variables. Later on, when the Gridview will be created, I check for the condition and paste the right GridView at this place. If a Grid in gridViewArticleGroups gets pressed, I set the condition to false.

```
bool condition = true;

@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var gridViewArticles = new GridView.builder(){};
  var gridViewArticleGroups= new GridView.builder(){};

  return Expanded(
    child: condition ? gridViewArticles : gridViewArticleGroups,
  );
}
```